# getting device serial number React native (expo) how to get the device ( serial number) unique id

Tags: react-native, expo, deviceid

I have a React Native application where multiple Android devices are connected. I need to obtain the serial number of each connected device to store it in a database. I attempted to retrieve the ID or serial using expo-device, but I was unsuccessful

Comment: If you want help fixing your code - that currently does not do what you want - then post it so that someone may help you fix it so that it does do what you want. I suggest that you read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info) library, gives various device related details.

Comment: i have alrady installed react-native-device-info 
and i have " import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info"  and i call it in app   DeviceInfo.getSerialNumber().then((serialNumber) => {
          console.log(serialNumber);
     });


i got such an error   Error: react-native-device-info: NativeModule.RNDeviceInfo is null. To fix this issue try these steps:

Comment: Well, the library does not require much setup. If it shows null then the problem might be in linking the library. try a few steps, remove and install again. with expo usually the command is `npx expo install react-native-device-info` which automatically links the library. Or you can create android folder and link manually.

Comment: i do all have the same i used such a code but i got "unkown  "


  const getDeviceSerialNumber2 = async () => {
    try {
      DeviceInfo.getSerialNumber().then(SerialNumber => {
        console.log('Device Serial Number--:', SerialNumber);
      });
      // return SerialNumber;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error getting device serial number:', error);
      return null;
    }
  };